# Manipulating a database in C++

Tags: database, visual-c++, c++-cli

I apologize if has been asked, and answered somewhere else, but I have been searching like crazy and can't find what I'm looking for.

```
OleDbConnection^ conn = gcnew OleDbConnection ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Milestone3testdatabase.accdb; Persist Security Info=True");
                 OleDbCommand^ com = gcnew OleDbCommand();
                    com->Connection = conn;
                    com->CommandText = "SELECT *FROM tblcity;";
                    System::Data::DataSet^ ds = gcnew System::Data::DataSet();
                OleDbDataAdapter^ adapt = gcnew OleDbDataAdapter();
                    adapt->SelectCommand = com;
                    adapt->Fill(ds,"why");

                    dataGridView1->DataSource = ds->Tables["why"];
```

I am trying to figure out how to actually use the data I obtain from the database. I was shown how to put it into a gridview, BUT I don't want a gridview. I want be able to take 1 cell of the table and display it as text.

How do I convert the table into usable data for a C++ forms application?

Comment: C++ and C++/CLI are not the same thing. In the future please try to tag your posts appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either modify your `SELECT` so that it returns only a single value by using [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) or extract the value from your table with the [DataTable.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataTable.Rows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
myDataTable->Rows[rowNumber][columnNumber]
```

Comment: I understand the sql select command, but once I do "adapt->Fill(ds,"why");" I don't know how to use this data other than putting into a gridview. I want use it in a combobox list, or print the text in label.

Comment: You have your `ds->Tables["why"]` which is a `DataTable`. You can read this like a two _dimensional array_ by rows and columns like in the example above. You can also use it as a datasource for your combobox. If you want to show something in a label you need to pick up just one cell/value or combine them into a string or something that is usefull for you.